# Creating Forms that use asp.Identity to pre-populate some data and create new entry to db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I have a site in progress that is using ASP.Identity to create new users. I have a secondary table with more user information I would like to be populated once the account is registered. As I already have the id and email, I don't need to ask for these again but can't get the second form to pass the data through the Create Razor page, even though it's displaying on the form itself.

I'm getting an error message when I submit saying the "LoginID is required", so how do I get the form to post with the value of userLoginId?

**Create Page**

```
var userLoginId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>nrLogins</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LoginID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => userLoginId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => userLoginId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

**LoginController**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "LoginID,Email,FirstName,LastName,DateOfBirth,Address1,Address2,Address3,Address4,Address5,PostCode,PhoneMobile,PhoneOther,UserSearchable,SiteRoleType,AccountActive,AccountCreatedDate,AccountEditedDate,AccountDeletedDate")] dbLogin dbLogin)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.dbLogins.Add(dbLogin);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(dbLogin);
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the name attribute for the control otherwise it default to your variable name which is userLoginId instead of LoginId, so you can do the following:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => userLoginId, null, "LoginId", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

If you don't want the user to be able to see or edit the details you can pass it as a hidden field

```
@Html.Hidden("LoginId", userLoginId)
```

Comment: Apologies, I can't upvote yet, but that worked perfectly. Thanks very much.  I'll keep the hidden option in mind too, once i get closer to a real view.